# "Ineffectual" vs "ineffective"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

> Skeptics argue that these kinds of initiatives are doomed to remain
>   perennially peripheral and ineffectual.

Intuitively,  changing *ineffectual* to *ineffective* in the sentence above seems to leave the meaning unchanged. Is there any difference between the two options?

[Here](http://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2011/07/the-new-foreign-policy-frontier/242593/) is the original source of the sentence.

Comment: I don't know why someone voted to close without giving a reason. I haven't yet checked a dictionary to see if there's any clear semantic space between the two words, but certainly I couldn't summarise very briefly the different contexts in which I would use each word.

Comment: ...there is also [inefficacious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inefficacious), which seems much the same to me, if a trifle "wordy".

Comment: It seems to me that the majority of answers provided are completely ineffectual in resolving the stated dilemma. They could be, however, simply ineffective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to think of these as having a slight difference:

- If something *is ineffectual*, it is not having an effect right now.
- If something *is ineffective*, it has been shown not to have an effect in the general case or the current situation.
- If something *was ineffectual*, it wasn't working as of the time context of the sentence.
- If something *was ineffective*, it did not work in a particular past situation.

So, *ineffectual* in my mind refers to the state of it having an effect at a specific point in time, either right now or at some definite point in the past. *Ineffective* refers to the state of it having an effect in general, or during a given "event" in the past (which may not be given a definite place in the timeline).

Disclaimer: this difference is probably all in my head, it's just my opinion, no research to back it up.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying however it makes me think that ineffectual was the wrong choice in the sentence above.

Answer (score 12):

I neither agree nor disagree with the fine distinction made by @KeithS, but I think most people will side with OP's "intuition", and think both words "mean" the same.

The biggest effect of changing *ineffectual* to *ineffective* is that the sentence would be more "snappy" and "modern". Here's a chart showing the written usage trend...

[image: .]

It's my guess that in using the older/more established/archaic term, the writer primarily intended to add a touch of [gravitas](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gravitas) to his text, rather than because it conveyed something subtly different to *ineffective* (along the lines of any suggestions here, or indeed any others). This I think is a common device in "persuasive writing", which does appear to be the context.

Comment: Or that graph could indicate that command of the English language has been decreasing over time.

Comment: @Jim: I don't really follow the logic of that. One word has declined, while another with similar/identical meaning has gained traction. Articulate speakers should be aware of both words, and ordinarily you'd expect them to use the one that's more common *today* - unless they're deliberately stepping out of line for reasons of style/nuance as suggested in my answer. Doggedly sticking with dated/outmoded usages doesn't strike me as evidence of "good command of English". Quite the reverse, in fact.

Answer (score 6):

*Ineffectual*, in my opinion, carries a more pejorative shade of meaning than the strictly utilitarian *ineffective*, which means simply not effective.  *Ineffectual* might be synonymous with "vain, useless, futile" while *ineffective* refers strictly to a specific outcome or aim not being realised.

Comment: I completely agree with Ricardo. "Ineffectual" implies the actor is at fault. "Ineffective" implies fault could be beyond the actor's control.

Answer (score 1):

*Ineffective* and *ineffectual*—both—refer to failure. But only *ineffectual* refers to the kind of failure that happens when the effort was weak, impotent, and/or incompetent.

- If a team of great lawyers fail to win a vigorously debated case, their efforts have been ineffective but not ineffectual.
- If, however, a team of pee-wee baseball players fail to defeat the New York Yankees, their efforts have been both ineffective *and* ineffectual.

Answer (score 0):

Just as *continual* means "apparently continuous", perhaps *ineffectual* means "apparently ineffective".

Comment: I think I might have to disagree with the analogy of continual/contiunous "is to" ineffectual/ineffective, being that doing something continually implies a repetition, whereas a continual event isn't necessarily continuous (i.e., without stopping), and by the way, wouldn't a quick check of the OED or Webster's provide the quickest solution? Apart from us old folks having more or less an equivalent to a language corpus in our brains due to vast experiences, there's no harm in consulting an engraved authority :)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think of ineffective as an assessment or statement of the 'result'; whereas ineffectual is a statement of an ongoing status.
In other words, ineffectual is the state of actually being ineffective. Something can only be ineffectual if it is being used; whereas many things that are not in use - objects and processes included - are know to be ineffective or can be assessed as such whilst never actually having been used.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is close but incorrect.

Ineffective means "not effective"

Usage: The program to reduce childhood obesity was ineffective.

Ineffectual means "will never produce the desired effect"

Usage: Programs to reduce childhood obesity are ineffectual.

From the original sample "doomed to remain perennially peripheral" is superfluous language which poetically implied "ineffectual". A better phrasing would've been "Skeptics argue these kind of programs are ineffectual."

IMO.